# 'Might pay you to do' - what does it mean?

Tags: modal-verbs

When your boss says: 'Might pay you to contact this client and advise them', what does 'pay' mean in this context?
Does it indicate he thinks you're not doing what you get paid for?

Comment: Perhaps an abbreviated version of "It might pay you..."

Comment: It is a figure of speech meaning he is offering advice.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, it means that you might reap some sort of reward (more sales, better reputation, etc.) by contacting the client.  Your boss isn't indicating that you're not doing what you're paid to do but that you'll get some benefit from doing as he suggests.

Per the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[pay](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pay)***
>
> VERB
>
> 1. *[with object]* Give (someone) money that is due for work done, goods received, or a debt incurred.
>        *[with object and infinitive] ‘the traveller paid a guide to show him across’*
>        *[no object] ‘I'll pay for your ticket’*
>
>    1.1 Give (a sum of money) in exchange for goods or work done or to settle a debt.
>       *‘the company was rumoured to have paid 450p a share’*
>       *[with two objects] ‘they paid him an annual retainer’*
>
>    1.2 Hand over or transfer the amount due of (a debt, wages, etc.) to someone.
>       *‘I always prefer to pay all my bills by cheque’*
>
>    1.3 (of work, an investment, etc.) provide someone with (a sum of money)
>       *‘jobs that pay £5 an hour’*
>
>    1.4 *[no object]* (of a business, activity, or an attitude) be profitable or advantageous.
>       *‘crime doesn't pay’*
>       *[with infinitive] ‘it pays to choose varieties carefully’*

Note especially the last definition I quoted (#1.4) with the infinitive.

Comment: I would go for meaning 1.4 even though there is an object (you) in the original question